# Append data to existing datatable

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

This is what I presently have

```
    Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("myconnectionstring")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim allSelectedTexts As New List(Of String)
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter=@parameter"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", parameter)

    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    sqlConnection1.Open()
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    myDataTable.Load(reader)
    sqlConnection1.Close()
    lbProduct.DataSource = myDataTable
    lbProduct.DataTextField = "product_name"
    lbProduct.DataValueField = "product_id"
    lbProduct.DataBind()
```

What I want to do is to query data to add onto this using a new parameter, how would I do that?

I need to get another table and append It onto this one

This is in a multiselect listbox, the first click will get data to add into a datasource, the second click will get other data. I was thinking I could loop through the elements I have selected then add it to the table before I set the datasource, but I don't know how to append to the table

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that you just need to know how to append to the datatable before setting the datasource.

You said you wanted to get another table appended to this one. If the schemas are the same (or very similar) you could use the DataTable.Merge method to bring the data together.

Alternatively if your other data is not in the same format, is not in a datatable, or otherwise you would prefer not to use this method, you could use the DataTable.Rows.Add method to write in the data line by line. In this case you would compile your data into an array, such as the following:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3, etc...)
```

Another option might be to bring your other data into another datatable if you wanted to make use of the DataTable.Merge method.

I hope this helps!

[DataTable.Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataTable.Rows.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx)